# Pasar de MySQLi a PDO

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
function mostrar_contenidos(){
  global $db, $limit_end;
$url = basename($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]);
$user_tipo = 'user';

if (isset($_GET['p']))
  $ini=$_GET['p'];
else
  $ini=1;

$init = ($ini-1) * $limit_end;

if (isset($_REQUEST['busqueda'])) {
  $busqueda = strtolower(e($_REQUEST['busqueda']));
} else {
  $busqueda = "";
}

if (empty($busqueda)) {
  $busqueda = "";
  $count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contenido";
  $query = "  SELECT * FROM contenido
           ORDER BY id  DESC
           LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
} else {
  $count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contenido WHERE (seccion LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR contenido LIKE '%$busqueda%')";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM 'contenido' WHERE (seccion LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR contenido LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id
  DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
}
  $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
  $row =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if (!$row){

        $mensaje  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar';
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" >';
      echo '<h3>';
      echo $mensaje;
      //unset($_SESSION['successmes']);
      echo '</h3>';
      echo '</div>';

      } else
      {

        $num = $db->query($count);
    $x = $num->fetch_array();
    $total = ceil($x[0]/$limit_end);

    echo '<h2 class ="mt-5">Editar Contenido</h2>';
    echo "<hr>";

    echo '<div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">';
        pag($ini, $limit_end, $total);
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<div class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">';
    pag_test($ini, $limit_end, $total);
    echo "</div>";

    // INICIA EL WHILE
    echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';

     $c = $db->query($query);
     $j = 1;

     $c = $db->query($query);
         while($row = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
      $date = date_create($row['fecha']);
      $fecha = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');

      $rowid = $row['id'];
      $seccion = $row['seccion'];
      $contenido = $row['contenido'];

      $boton_editar = '<a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" href="editar_contenido.php?id='.$rowid.'" data-toggle="popover" title=EDITAR CONTENIDO" data-content="Editar este contenido.">
      Editar
      </a>';

$accion = '<div class="btn-group" >'. $boton_editar. '</div>';

$a = '
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header" id="headingOne'.$rowid.'">
         <h5 class="row mb-0">
           <button class="btn btn-link col-12" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne'.$rowid.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne'.$rowid.'">

      <div class="row no-gutters">
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-start col-sm-8">'.$rowid.' Seccion: '. $seccion.' contenido('. $seccion.')</div>
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-end col-sm-4">'.$accion.'
         </div>
    </div>

           </button>
         </h5>
       </div>

       <div id="collapseOne'.$rowid.'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne'.$rowid.'" data-parent="#accordionExample">
         <div class="card-body">';
         
         $ct = substr($contenido,0,600) .".......";
         $ct = strip_tags($ct, "<img><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><br><p><b>");
         $a .= $ct;
    $a .='       </div>
         </div>
       </div>
         ';
   echo $a;
          }
    //$a .= '</tbody></table>';

echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">';
    pag($ini, $limit_end, $total);
echo "</div>";
echo '<div class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">';
pag_test($ini, $limit_end, $total);
echo "</div>";

    }
```

Pero requiero pasar a PDO he intentado lo siguiente pero no he tenido exito en la paginacion.

```
function mostrar_contenidos(){
  global $conn, $limit_end;
$url = basename($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]);
$user_tipo = 'user';

if (isset($_GET['p']))
  $ini=$_GET['p'];
else
  $ini=1;

$init = ($ini-1) * $limit_end;

if (isset($_REQUEST['busqueda'])) {
  $busqueda = strtolower(e($_REQUEST['busqueda']));
} else {
  $busqueda = "";
}

if (empty($busqueda)) {
  $busqueda = "";
  $count= $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contenido");
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM contenido
           ORDER BY id  DESC
           LIMIT $init, $limit_end");
} else {
  $count= $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contenido WHERE (seccion LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR contenido LIKE '%$busqueda%')");
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'contenido' WHERE (seccion LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR contenido LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id
  DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end");
}
  //$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count->execute();
  //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $row =  $count->rowCount();
  if (!$row){

      $mensaje  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar';
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" >';
      echo '<h3>';
      echo $mensaje;
      //unset($_SESSION['successmes']);
      echo '</h3>';
      echo '</div>';

      } else
      {

    //$num = $db->query($count);
    $num = $row;

        $x = $count->fetchColumn();
    $total = ceil($x[0]/$limit_end);

    echo '<h2 class ="mt-5">Editar Contenido</h2>';
    echo "<hr>";

    echo '<div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">';
        pag($ini, $limit_end, $total);
    echo "</div>";
    echo '<div class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">';
    pag_test($ini, $limit_end, $total);
    echo "</div>";

    // INICIA EL WHILE
    echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';

     // $c = $db->query($query);
     $c = $num;
     $j = 1;
         while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          {
      $date = date_create($row['fecha']);
      $fecha = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');

      $rowid = $row['id'];
      $seccion = $row['seccion'];
      $contenido = $row['contenido'];

      $boton_editar = '<a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm" href="../editar_contenido/?id='.$rowid.'" data-bs-toggle="popover" title=EDITAR CONTENIDO" data-bs-content="Editar este contenido.">
      Editar
      </a>';

$accion = '<div class="btn-group" >'. $boton_editar. '</div>';

$a = '
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header" id="headingOne'.$rowid.'">
         <h5 class="row mb-0">
           <button class="btn btn-link col-12" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne'.$rowid.'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne'.$rowid.'">

      <div class="row no-gutters">
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-start col-sm-8">'.$rowid.' Seccion: '. $seccion.' contenido('. $seccion.')</div>
           <div class="d-flex justify-content-end col-sm-4">'.$accion.'
         </div>
    </div>

           </button>
         </h5>
       </div>

       <div id="collapseOne'.$rowid.'" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne'.$rowid.'" data-parent="#accordionExample">
         <div class="card-body">';
         //$a .= $contenido;
         $ct = substr($contenido,0,600) .".......";
         $ct = strip_tags($ct, "<img><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><br><p><b>");
         $a .= $ct;


    $a .='       </div>
         </div>
       </div>
         ';
   echo $a;
          }

echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">';
    pag($ini, $limit_end, $total);
echo "</div>";
echo '<div class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-none">';
pag_test($ini, $limit_end, $total);
echo "</div>";

    }



  }
```

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir exactamente *no he tenido exito en la paginacion*? Explica qué hace el código actualmente: ¿da error? ¿qué error? ¿no hace nada, quedándose la pantalla en blanco? ¿muestra algo, pero no es lo que esperas? ¿qué muestra y qué debería mostrar? Por otra parte, tu código tiene algunas malas prácticas: deberías evitar `PHP_SELF` y deberías evitar `rowCount()` para consultas del tipo `SELECT`, además es redundante lo que haces. Aquí obtienes el total de filas: `$x = $count->fetchColumn();`, trabaja con eso desde el principio y no uses `rowCount()`

Answer (score 0):

puedes crear una clase para manejar la conexiones a la base de datos para que no tengas este problema a futuro ejemplo:

1. cs hace referencia a consulta simple
2. cr hace referencia a consulta retorna

ejemplo:

```
class Dbconnect{

  private $db = {
    "host"=> "localhost",
    "dbname" => "database1",
    "username" => "username",
    "password" => "passsword"

  }
  private $conn = null;

  function __construct(){
    $this->conn = new \PDO("mysql:host={$this->db['host']};dbname={$this->db['dbname']}", $this->db['username'], $this->db['password']);
  }

  public function cs($sql,$rows){
    $stmt= $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    return $stmt->execute($rows);
  }

  public function cr($sql,$rows){
    $data = array();
    $query =$this->conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    if(!$query->execute($rows)) return false;

    while ($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
      $data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $data
  }
}


$db = new Dbconnect();

$insert = "INSERT INTO users (name, surname, sex) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$db->cs($insert,[$name, $surname, $sex]);

$select = 'SELECT * FROM users where surname = ?';
$data = $db->cs($select,[$name, $surname, $sex]);
```

con ello solo tendras que modificar la consulta a futuro si quieres utilizar otra base de datos u otro conector.